# Generating all possible combinations in a range using numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy, combinations

I am looking for an efficient way to generate all possible combinations within a certain big range using numpy or any faster method. I tried:

```
from numpy import *
from itertools import *

dt=dtype('i,i,i,i,i,i')
fromiter(combinations(range(10000000),6), dtype=dt, count=-1)
```

but I get a memory error, and even if it worked it will likely take forever to complete. I am looking for combinations that dont repeat. For example, if I needed all 3 number combinations in range(1,5) I will get (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4).

Comment: There are 1.3888868e+39 sequences that you are trying to generate. Of course you will get a memory error.

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? Even if you crammed all the number into single bits (not possible), you would still not have enough memory. Or time.

Comment: Note, even if each iteration took 1 nanosecond (1.388e39 * 1e-9) it would still take 4.4x10^22 years, or 3.2x10^12 times the age of the known universe to go through 1.3888868e39 iterations necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is around 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
 (1 Septillion) possible combinations of 6 elements with the range you are using. You'll never process them all. The best you can do is to process them in the "lazy way" with a iterator:

```
for c in combinations(range(10000000),6):
    print(c)
```