# Subset sum improvement

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, sum, subset

**SHORT version:**

Is there a way with numpy (in python) to calculate all sum combinations possibilities from a float array between two intervals?

**FULL (long) version:**

With the help of multiple threads from Reddit, I do this subset sum program to find the closer weight combinations values. (the result must be higher but as close as possible, and I need to see all combinations)

```
def subset(array, num, epsilon):
result = []
def find(arr, num, path=()):
    if not arr:
        return
    if (arr[0] >= num and arr[0] <= num + epsilon):
        result.append(path + (arr[0],))
    else:
        find(arr[1:], num - arr[0], path + (arr[0],))
        find(arr[1:], num, path)
find(array, num)
return result

def sumColumn(matrix):
    return numpy.sum(matrix, axis=1)  # axis=1 says "get the sum along the columns"


target = 7.00
suppaumaxde = 0.30

#data = [  1.98, 1.93, 1.64,  2.06, 2.18, 2.12, 3.20, 1.29, 2*0.65, 1.84*2, 1.85*2]
#, 1.58*3, 1.46*3, (1.48*3+0.22), 1.12*4, 1.85*2, 2*1.84, 2*1.84, 1.18*3, 2.38+0.02, 0.65*5,

data = [  1.13, 2.26, 3.93, 2.40-0.02, 2.38, 2.27, 1.98, 1.93, 1.64,  2.06, 2.18, 2.12, 3.20, 1.29, 2*0.65, 1.84*2,
 1.85*2, 1.58*3, 1.46*3, (1.48*3+0.22), 1.12*4, 1.85*2, 2*1.84, 1.18*3, 2.38+0.02, 0.65*5,
 3.23, 1.60, 0.58, 4.01, 1.09*3]

print data
Resultat=subset(data, target, suppaumaxde)
#print subset(data, target, suppaumaxde)
#print(' '.join(map(str, Resultat)))
#print([sum(row) for row in Resultat])
couleur='\33[37m'
print('\n')
for colonne in Resultat:
    if (sum(colonne)<=target+(suppaumaxde*1/3)):couleur='\33[42m'
    elif (sum(colonne)<=target+(suppaumaxde*2/3)):couleur='\33[43m'
    elif (sum(colonne)<=target+(suppaumaxde*3/3)):couleur='\033[91m'
    print couleur,sum(colonne),'\033[0m',(colonne)


data.sort(reverse=True)
print('\n')
print data
Resultat=subset(data, target, suppaumaxde)
#print(' '.join(map(str, Resultat)))
print('\n')
for colonne in Resultat:
    if (sum(colonne)<=target+(suppaumaxde*1/3)):couleur='\33[42m'
    elif (sum(colonne)<=target+(suppaumaxde*2/3)):couleur='\33[43m'
    elif (sum(colonne)<=target+(suppaumaxde*3/3)):couleur='\033[91m'
    print couleur,sum(colonne),'\033[0m',(colonne)


data.sort()
print('\n')
print data
Resultat=subset(data, target, suppaumaxde)
#print(' '.join(map(str, Resultat)))
print('\n')
for colonne in Resultat:
    if (sum(colonne)<=target+(suppaumaxde*1/3)):couleur='\33[42m'
    elif (sum(colonne)<=target+(suppaumaxde*2/3)):couleur='\33[43m'
    elif (sum(colonne)<=target+(suppaumaxde*3/3)):couleur='\033[91m'
    print couleur,sum(colonne),'\033[0m',(colonne)
```

It started to work but I have to improve things:

1. If I order the array differently, I get different results. So I think some result are missing. (that's why I repeat the display code 3 times without doing a function, to show this. But I want to remove the two last ones)
2. The execution time becomes long since I add some more input in an array. Maybe this is not optimized and does too many operations. Maybe ordering before comparing and once the limit value as been reached pass to next item?
3. Ideally, I liked to order my results but without adding too much execution time.
4. Some result appears multiple times (as a second point I think some optimization is missing)

I just begin using python so I didn't understand the whole program, if you do, I would be happy to improve this with your advice :)

I post this too on Reddit this morning and Laserdude10642 talk about numpy,
So after starting RTFM, It seems to be a good option to be more efficient, I tried a little by finding other examples:

```
import numpy as np

def find_nearest(array, value):
array = np.asarray(array)
idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
return array[idx]


montab = [  2.95, 2.26, 3.93, 2.38*2, 1.98, 1.93, 1.64, 0.53, 1.20, 2.06, 2.18, 2.12, 3.20, 1.29, 1.20, 2*0.65, 1.84*2,
 1.85*2, 1.58*3, 1.46*3, (1.48*3+0.22), 1.12*4, 1.18*3, 2.38+0.02, 0.65*5,
 3.23, 1.60, 0.58, 4.01, 1.09*3, 0.60]

cible= 7

print(find_nearest(montab, cible))
```

But I need to display all results that are in the asymmetric interval

Is there a way with numpy to calculate all sum combinations possible between two intervals?

PS1: sorry for my poor English :/

PS2: Ideally I like the code to stay more easily understandable, so it's easier to modify it afterward

PS3: I launch my python program inside Geany (on Linux Mint) the execute command is "python "%f", is there a simple way to lunch it on multiple cores to go faster? (without adapting the program for multi-thread?)

PS4: It is not possible to start a question by "Hi" or "Hello"? I tried both but disappears each time.

Comment: This is far too broad. What is it specifically that you're asking?

Comment: Oh sorry :/
To be very short:
Is there a way with numpy (in python) to calculate all sum combinations possibilities from a float array between two intervals?

Answer (score 0):

I found an other solution but still not a good solution based on this [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869644/generating-all-possible-combinations-in-a-range-using-numpy-in-python):

```
from numpy import *
from itertools import *

montab = [  2.95, 2.26, 3.93, 2.38*2, 1.98, 1.93, 1.64, 0.53, 1.20, 2.06, 2.18, 2.12, 3.20, 1.29, 1.20, 2*0.65, 1.84*2,
 1.85*2, 1.58*3, 1.46*3, (1.48*3+0.22), 1.12*4, 1.18*3, 2.38+0.02, 0.65*5,
 3.23, 1.60, 0.58, 4.01, 1.09*3, 0.60, 0, 0]

target=7
suppaumaxde = 0.35


print montab
montab.sort(reverse=True)
print montab
couleur='\33[37m'
print('\n')
for colonne in combinations(montab,4):
    if (sum(colonne)>=target and sum(colonne)<=target+suppaumaxde):
        if (sum(colonne)<=target+(suppaumaxde*1/3)):couleur='\33[42m'
        elif (sum(colonne)<=target+(suppaumaxde*2/3)):couleur='\33[43m'
        elif (sum(colonne)<=target+(suppaumaxde*3/3)):couleur='\033[91m'
        print couleur,sum(colonne),'\033[0m',(colonne)
```

But the result isn't good and has to be improved / find an other solution :

1. I have to set a number of items and to add zero's in the data array
2. All combinations are tested it's a big time loose
3. The result isn't sorted